# So basically, i can't get the sorted function in Python to work

Tags: python, dictionary

Im working on this segment of my code where i have to get the 10 most frequent words in a dictionary.
I got my code to somewhat work, but it gets the wrong output.

```
def countWords():


Counts = {}
              
for x in wordList:
   if not x in Counts:      
      Counts[x] = wordList.count(x)
      
return Counts

def getMostFrequent():

exclWordList = tuple(englConj), tuple(englPrep), tuple(englPronouns), tuple(specialWords)

topFreqWords =  dict(sorted(Counts.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[:topNumber])
tfw = {}
i=1
for item in topFreqWords:
    for ew in exclWordList:
        if ew not in topFreqWords:
            tfw[item] = i
            i += 1

return tfw


if __name__ == "__main__":

trimmedText = loadBook()
newTextList = removeNL_and_doLowerCase()
nTL = doubleDashToSpace()  

  
specialChars = ['.', ',', ':', ';',  '[', ']', '(', ')', "'s", '"',
                '*', '&', '!', '?']

nTL = deleteSpecChar()
wordList = splitter()

Counts = countWords()



englPrep = ['about', 'beside', 'near', 'to', 'above', 'between', 'of', 
            'towards', 'across', 'beyond', 'off', 'under', 'after', 'by',
            'on', 'underneath', 'against', 'despite', 'onto', 'unlike', 
            'along', 'down', 'opposite', 'until', 'among', 'during', 'out', 
            'up', 'around', 'except', 'outside', 'along', 'as', 'for', 
            'over', 'via', 'at', 'from', 'past', 'with', 'before', 'in', 
            'round', 'within', 'behind', 'inside', 'since', 'without', 
            'below', 'into', 'than', 'beneath', 'like', 'through']

englConj = ['for', 'and', 'nor', 'but', 'or', 'yet', 'so']

englPronouns = ['you', 'he', 'she', 'him', 'her', 'his', 'hers', 'yours']

specialWords = ['the']
topNumber = 10
tfw = getMostFrequent()
```

So basically, tfw returns a dictionary that is 10 keys long, but it returns just 10 random keys it seems like. I think the issue is that the Counts dict. isn't sorted, and i cant get that to work either. Also i think that the topFreqWords isn't getting sorted either. idk really.
Im kinda stuck now.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the current and expected output. I would also recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: I know this sounds like something trivial, but please delete the words 'So basically', from the title and the last paragraph. They don't add any meaning, and might irritate people.

Answer (score 0):

My attempt at replicating the dict(sorted(...)) action worked fine in version 3.8 (The code you posted is out of order, missing indents, and function definitions so there may be other problems).

First, check your python version.  If you are using a version of python prior to 3.7, then the dict object does not maintain insertion order and will return the items in what appears to be random order (though there is method to the madness).

If you are using an older version, you'd either have to use a collectoins.OrderedDict, or make topFreqWords a list instead of a dict:

```
topFreqWords =  list(sorted(Counts.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[:topNumber])
```

then in the for loop, you can state

```
for item,count in topFreqWords:
...
```